# Can't find tmp folder in php. (Ubuntu 10.10, apache2)

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, apache2

I have a form, which uploads an image.
I try to get it by `$_FILES`:

```
$filename = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
$source = $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name']."/".$filename;
$target = GL_UPLOADPATH.$filename;

echo "TEST0";        

if (move_uploaded_file($source, $target)) {
    //connect to DB and so on, what I need

    echo "TEST1";
}
```

So I get echoed `TEST0` but don't get echoed `TEST1`.
If I echo every variable - it's normal. I see my `$target` - it's something like `/tmp/phpoLqYdj/test2.jpg`

So, I think PHP can't `move_uploaded_file` because it can't find `/tmp/phpoLqYdj/test2.jpg`

But where is `/tmp/phpoLqYdj/`? I am testing on localhost. My document root is `/var/www/`. 
PHP has default settings in php.ini (upload_tmp_dir is commented in php.ini).

In my `/tmp/` folder (in system) I don't have such folder like `php***`. In `/var/tmp/`  either.

(Ubuntu 10.10, LAMP was installed by "tasksel")

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Yes, by default it was turned off. And I turned it on by:
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: php doesn't post any error :( I think move_uploaded_file just return false as failed and "if body" is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uploads files via PHP, it stores them in as a tmp file that's not named anything related to the filename.  Appending `$filename` to `$_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name']` is the incorrect way to handle it... `$_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name']` IS the file.

Also, the tmp file is removed at the end of the request, so you'll never have a chance to actually see it in the file manager.  Either you move it in the same request, or it's gone.  It's all done in the name of security.

Anyway, just use this instead and you'll be good.

```
$filename = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
$source = $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'];
$target = GL_UPLOADPATH.$filename;

echo "TEST0";        

if (move_uploaded_file($source, $target)) {
    //connect to DB and so on, what I need

    echo "TEST1";
}
```

Comment: >> $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'] IS the file.
Oh, understood. Thanks. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. What I did to fix it was change the permissions of folder that you are uploading to, to read and write for all.